# How to make the table fit to the mobile screen size in css/html?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, inspect

I have a table on the webpage which I am trying to make responsive(fit to the screen size) but unfortunately the table is going out of the screen in the mobile view for some reasons. The pictorial represenation of what I want in a mobile view is:

[image]

At this moment after inspection, I am able to get the following image in a mobile view (which is going out of the screen):

[image: DependentsTable]

The div class = "section header single" points to the 1st ROW having the "Dependents" text. The HTML code for it is:

```
<div class="section header single">
    <div class="inter">
        <!-- ko i18n:'dependents' -->Dependents<!-- /ko -->
        <div class="info header-sections" data-bind="popup: {
                    popupId: 'info-popup',
                    closeOnOutsideClick: true,
                    vm: {title: '', message: depend_info[locale.selected_locale()]}
                }"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above image is in the inspect mode and in the mobile view(in between 320px and 767px) as well and it is going out of the screen which I am trying to resolve.  The CSS(mobile view) and CSS(desktop view) which I am using for the above image are-

CSS Mobile View for the 1st row containing the text "Dependents":

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 768px)
  {
 .default-body .section.header.single 
  {                                                       
  background: none !important;
  background-color:#656364 !important;
  border: 1px solid #bfbfbf !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  margin-top:0px !important;
   }
   }


 .section.header 
  {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0px !important;
  width: 100%;  
  }

    .section 
  {
  height: auto;
  display: table;   
  }

 .default-body .section.header.single {
background: url(img/section-bg-BenPal.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0 #0359a6 !important;
border: 1px solid #bfbfbf !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
top: 0 !important;
margin-top: 40px !important;}
```

CSS Desktop View for the 1st row containing the text "Dependents":

```
.section.header.single {
    top: 0;
}
.default-body .section.header {
    background-color: #0a2f73;
    border: 1px solid #0a2f73;
}
.section.header {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    padding: 10px 0px !important;
    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.section.single {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.section {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    display: table;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

My task is to make the entire table fit to the mobile screen. I have tried using width: auto or 100% but still the table is going out of the screen for some reasons. In the parent classes as well, I have changed the width to 100% or auto but still the table is going out of the screen.

In order to make the things more clear, I am including the HTML and CSS codes for the content beneath the "Dependents" text row:

The HTML code for the content beneath the Dependents row is:

```
<div class="section single">
    <div class="inter">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table title">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="cell1"><!-- ko i18n:'dependents.name' -->Name<!-- /ko --></td>
                <td class="cell2"><!-- ko i18n:'dependents.type' -->Type<!-- /ko --></td>
                <td class="cell3"><!-- ko i18n:'dependents.status' -->Status<!-- /ko --></td>
                <td class="cell4 last"></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody><tbody data-bind="foreach: dependents"></tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- ko ifnot: pendingApproval || viewReadonlyBenefits-->
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table">
            <tbody><tr data-bind="css:{hidden: dependents().length != 0}" class=""><td colspan="3" class="cell-common"><!--ko i18n: 'dependents.no.dependent' -->There is no dependent registered in your file<!--/ko--></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <!-- ko if: showAddButton() --><!-- /ko -->
           </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code(Desktop view) for the content beneath the "Dependents" text row is:

```
.section.single {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.section {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    display: table;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.section {
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #aecaea;
    border-right: 1px solid #aecaea;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aecaea;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC !important;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

I am also including the snapshot of the webpage corresponding to above HTML and  CSS codes:[image]:

The CSS code for the mobile view corresponding to the content beneath the "Dependents" text row is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 320px)
.section.single {
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
}
.section.single {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.section {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    display: table;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.section {
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #aecaea;
    border-right: 1px solid #aecaea;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aecaea;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #CCCCCC !important;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Did you add the viewport meta?

Comment: Yes, I have added it.

Comment: can u put your code in codepen or jsfiddle?